# Select Row in Resco SmartGrid

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am using Resco Controls Smart grid in Windows compact framework device, I want to select full row either on smart grid cell click event or on button click event. In my case selection mode of smart grid is Full Row Select. I cannot find any Selected method in resco smart grid. Please help if anyone know how can select smart grid row programatically.

Answer (score 0):

The base DataGrid class has a Select(int row) / UnSelect(int row) method that you can use for this.

Example to select the first row:

dg.Select(0);